# Error with asynchronous request in DRF

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, python-asyncio

I need to fulfill a request to two services. 
The code looks like this:

```
async def post1(data):
    response = await aiohttp.request('post', 'http://', json=data)
    json_response = await response.json()
    response.close()
    return json_response

async def get2():
    response = await aiohttp.request('get', 'http://')
    json_response = await response.json()
    response.close()
    return json_response

async def asynchronous(parameters):

    task1 = post1(parameters['data'])
    task2 = get2()

    result_list = []
    for body in await asyncio.gather(task1, task2):
        result_list.append(body)
    return result_list
```

If I run the code locally, it's OK. The code looks like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    parameters = {'data': data}
    result = ioloop.run_until_complete(asynchronous(parameters))
    ioloop.close()
    print(result)
```

I get the right result. But if I try to execute code from the DRF method, an error occurs:

> TypeError: object _SessionRequestContextManager can't be used in
>   'await' expression

example code that I run:

```
 .....
 class MyViewSet(GenericAPIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        ......

        ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        result = ioloop.run_until_complete(asynchronous(serializer.data)) # <<<<< error here
        ioloop.close()

        ......
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Please, tell me what the problem may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object returned by `aiohttp.request` cannot be awaited, it must be used as an async context manager. This code:

```
response = await aiohttp.request('post', 'http://', json=data)
json_response = await response.json()
response.close()
```

needs to changed to something like:

```
async with aiohttp.request('post', 'http://', json=data) as response:
    json_response = await response.json()
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request) for more usage examples.

Perhaps you have a different aiohttp version on the server where you run DRF, which is why it works locally and fails under DRF.

Answer (score 0):

Try it https://github.com/Skorpyon/aiorestframework

Create some middleware for authentication:

```
import re
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
from multidict import MultiDict, MultiDictProxy

from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.hdrs import (
    METH_POST, METH_PUT, METH_PATCH, METH_DELETE
)

from aiorestframework import exceptions
from aiorestframework omport serializers
from aiorestframework import Response
from aiorestframework.views import BaseViewSet
from aiorestframework.permissions import set_permissions, AllowAny
from aiorestframework.app import APIApplication

from my_project.settings import Settings  # Generated by aiohttp-devtools


TOKEN_RE = re.compile(r'^\s*BEARER\s{,3}(\S{64})\s*$')

async def token_authentication(app, handler):
    """
    Authorization middleware
    Catching Authorization: BEARER <token> from request headers
    Found user in Tarantool by token and bind User or AnonymousUser to request
    """
    async def middleware_handler(request):
        # Check that `Authorization` header exists
        if 'authorization' in request.headers:
            authorization = request.headers['authorization']
            # Check matches in header value
            match = TOKEN_RE.match(authorization)
            if not match:
                setattr(request, 'user', AnonymousUser())
                return await handler(request)
            else:
                token = match[1]
        elif 'authorization_token' in request.query:
            token = request.query['authorization_token']
        else:
            setattr(request, 'user', AnonymousUser())
            return await handler(request)

        # Try select user auth record from Tarantool by token index
        res = await app['tnt'].select('auth', [token, ])
        cached = res.body
        if not cached:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed()

        # Build basic user data and bind it to User instance
        record = cached[0]
        user = User()
        user.bind_cached_tarantool(record)

        # Add User to request
        setattr(request, 'user', user)

        return await handler(request)
    return middleware_handler
```

And for data extraction from request:

```
DATA_METHODS = [METH_POST, METH_PUT, METH_PATCH, METH_DELETE]
JSON_CONTENT = ['application/json', ]
XML_CONTENT = ['application/xml', ]
FORM_CONTENT = ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'multipart/form-data']

async def request_data_handler(app, handler):
    """
    Request .data middleware
    Try extract POST data or application/json from request body
    """
    async def middleware_handler(request):
        data = None
        if request.method in DATA_METHODS:
            if request.has_body:
                if request.content_type in JSON_CONTENT:
                    # If request has body - try to decode it to JSON
                    try:
                        data = await request.json()
                    except JSONDecodeError:
                        raise exceptions.ParseError()
                elif request.content_type in XML_CONTENT:
                    if request.charset is not None:
                        encoding = request.charset
                    else:
                        encoding = api_settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
                    parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding=encoding)
                    try:
                        text = await request.text()
                        tree = etree.XML(text, parser=parser)
                    except (etree.ParseError, ValueError) as exc:
                        raise exceptions.ParseError(
                            detail='XML parse error - %s' % str(exc))
                    data = tree
                elif request.content_type in FORM_CONTENT:
                    data = await request.post()

        if data is None:
            # If not catch any data create empty MultiDictProxy
            data = MultiDictProxy(MultiDict())

        # Attach extracted data to request
        setattr(request, 'data', data)

        return await handler(request)
    return middleware_handler
```

Create few serializers:

```
class UserRegisterSerializer(s.Serializer):
    """Register new user"""
    email = s.EmailField(max_length=256)
    password = s.CharField(min_length=8, max_length=64)
    first_name = s.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=64)
    middle_name = s.CharField(default='', min_length=2, max_length=64, 
                              required=False, allow_blank=True)
    last_name = s.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=64)
    phone = s.CharField(max_length=32, required=False,
                        allow_blank=True, default='')

    async def register_user(self, app):
        user = User()
        data = self.validated_data
        try:
            await user.register_user(data, app)
        except Error as e:
            resolve_db_exception(e, self)
       return user
```

And few ViewSets. It may be nested in `bindings['custom']`

```
class UserViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    name = 'user'
    lookup_url_kwarg = '{user_id:[0-9a-f]{32}}'
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
    bindings = {
        'list': {
            'retrieve': 'get',
            'update': 'put'
        },
        'custom': {
            'list': {
                'set_status': 'post',
                'create_new_sip_password': 'post',
                'get_registration_domain': 'get',
                'report': UserReportViewSet
            }
        }
    }

    @staticmethod
    async def resolve_sip_host(data, user, app):
        sip_host = await resolve_registration_switch(user, app)
        data.update({'sip_host': sip_host})

    async def retrieve(self, request):
        user = User()
        await user.load_from_db(request.match_info['user_id'], request.app)

        serializer = user_ser.UserProfileSerializer(instance=user)
        data = serializer.data
        await self.resolve_sip_host(data, user, request.app)
        return Response(data=data)

    @atomic
    @set_permissions([AuthenticatedOnly, IsCompanyMember, CompanyIsEnabled])
    async def update(self, request):
        serializer = user_ser.UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = await serializer.update_user(user_id=request.user.id,
                                            app=request.app)

        serializer = user_ser.UserProfileSerializer(instance=user)
        data = serializer.data
        await self.resolve_sip_host(data, user, request.app)

        return Response(data=data)
```

Register Viewsets and run Application:

```
def setup_routes(app: APIApplication):
    """Add app routes here"""
    # Auth API
    app.router.register_viewset('/auth', auth_vws.AuthViewSet())
    # User API
    app.router.register_viewset('/user', user_vws.UserViewSet())
    # Root redirection to Swagger
    redirect = app.router.add_resource('/', name='home_redirect')
    redirect.add_route('*', swagger_redirect)


def create_api_app():
    sentry = get_sentry_middleware(settings.SENTRY_CONNECT_STRING, settings.SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT)
    middlewares = [sentry, token_authentication, request_data_handler]
    api_app = APIApplication(name='api', middlewares=middlewares, 
client_max_size=10*(1024**2))

    api_app.on_startup.append(startup.startup_api)
    api_app.on_shutdown.append(startup.shutdown_api)
    api_app.on_cleanup.append(startup.cleanup_api)

    setup_routes(api_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_api_app()
    web.run_app(app)
```